# File into nested array in PHP

Tags: php, file, parsing, recursion

I have a txt file in this format

```
-Main
--Sub
--Next sub
---Sub Sub
--Last sub
-Next Main
-Last Main
--Sub
--Next sub
```

and I need to convert it to the nested array

```
Array(
 "Main" => array("Sub","Next sub" => array("Sub Sub")),
);
```

Is there any recursive function to do that in PHP?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not very beautiful but the code works.

```
    $str = "
-Main
--Sub level 2
--Next sub level 2
---Sub Sub1 level 3
---Sub Sub2 level 3
--Last sub level 2
-Next Main
-Last Main
--Sub level 2
--Next sub level 2
--Next sub level 2
--Next sub level 2
---Next sub1 level 3
---Next sub2 level 3
---Next sub3 level 3
--Next sub level 2
-Next sub
--Next sub level 2
--Next sub level 2
";
$a = explode("\n", $str);
$last_count = 1;
$level = array();
$level1 = array();
$level2 = array();
$level3 = array();
$max_level = 0;
$min_level = 1;

foreach($a as $key => $val)
{
$count = substr_count($val, '-');
if ($max_level < $count)
{
$max_level = $count;
}
}

foreach($a as $key => $val)
{
$count = substr_count($val, '-');
$val = trim($val, '-');
if ($count > 0)
{
if ($count == $min_level)
{
$level1[] = $level2;
if ($last_count == 2)
{
$level1[] = $val;
}

$level1[] = $level2;
$level2 = array();
$level1[] = $val;
}
elseif ($count == ($max_level - 1) && ($last_count >= $min_level))
{
if ($last_count == $max_level)
{
array_pop($level2);
$level2[$name2] = $level3;
$level3 = array();
}

$level2[] = $val;
$name2 = $val;
}
elseif ($count == $max_level && ($last_count >= ($min_level + 1)))
{
$level3[] = $val;
}

$last_count = $count;
}
}

$level1[] = $level2;
$level1 = array_filter($level1);
$arr = array();

foreach($level1 as $key)
{
$arr[$var] = is_array($key) ? $key : '';
$var = $key;
}

$arr = array_filter($arr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
 Array
(
    [Main] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sub level 2
            [Next sub level 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sub Sub1 level 3
                    [1] => Sub Sub2 level 3
                )

            [1] => Last sub level 2
        )

    [Last Main] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sub level 2
            [1] => Next sub level 2
            [2] => Next sub level 2
            [Next sub level 2 ] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Next sub1 level 3
                    [1] => Next sub2 level 3
                    [2] => Next sub3 level 3
                )

            [3] => Next sub level 2
        )

    [Next sub] => Array
        (
            [0] => Next sub level 2
            [1] => Next sub level 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simply exploding the file content will do the job so to get you started:

```
$file = fopen('path/to/file.txt', "r");
$array = explode('/r',$file);
```

It's basic but from here, you can then manipulate it into nested arrays.

Comment: You might want to double-check what is returned by [fopen()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)